# How to integrate a chat feature without using the device messaging app

Tags: android, instant-messaging

Have 2 apps on separate devices: Rider & Driver.

Let's say, the Driver needs to contact the Rider via messaging, or vice versa, is there a way to do it without using the stocked message app to protect privacy?

My idea was to create on both apps an empty box, add a text view for the message and send button and add the msgs to firebase db. Unfortunately, i am not sure how i would do it in Android as well as the response.

Any suggestions or how to's would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use Firebase Services.

Comment: for instance?  .... notifications?

Comment: Using Firebase services for messaging and notifications too.

Comment: I have notifications but that won't work in this case.. lets say the driver needs to verify the location of the rider., sometimes the coordinates don't exactly give the correct address - some sort of messaging feature would work, but I don't know how

Comment: That's what I am saying, Have a look at Firebase and you can make a messaging app using it. [Reference Link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably integrate your app with **Firebase**.

For simple messaging, you could use `Firebase Cloud Firestore` to do it and for notification, you can use `Firebase Cloud Messaging`.

**Messaging**

You can have a sub-collection to store all the chats between the rider and driver in the form of documents.  1 chat will be a document storing the info such as time, sender, as well as message.

**Notification**

[From the doc:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?authuser=0)

> Send acknowledgments, chats, and other messages from devices back to
>   your server over FCM’s reliable and battery-efficient connection
>   channel.

You could start research from [Firebase sample application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/).

Highly recommend you go through this third party tutorial: [Firebase Tutorial: Real-time Chat](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5359-firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat)  to get some idea, it's in iOS but the concept is the same.

Comment: I was thinking more of this idea ... when the rider or driver click on a chat bubble button, it opens an empty box where they can type their message and then click SEND.  Then the person receiving the msg, sees a flashing button where it opens the msg so they can read or respond.  The chats can be stored to the db.Anyone have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: I guess that would be another question as you did not state it earlier

Comment: Not really. I am still trying to integrate a messaging feature into my app. It can still use firebase. I just dont want to create a chat app and integrate that into the app

Comment: I found a youtube tutorial that pretty much does what you suggested.  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hn_wfTqFbdg&t=547s
Thanks for the help and the direction :)

Comment: I did follow that series before, great that you found it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do it.

Actually you can use any messaging platform, e.g. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/), [Twillio](https://www.twilio.com/), [Layer](https://layer.com/) etc.

All of them provide API & SDK for iOS, Android and Web for chat so you can easily do it using it.

I used ConnectyCube some time ago, it can be done in the following way:

1. [Initialize app](https://developers.connectycube.com/android/)
2. [Sign Up user](https://developers.connectycube.com/android/authentication-and-users?id=user-signup)
3. [Connect to chat](https://developers.connectycube.com/android/messaging?id=connect-to-chat)
4. [Create a chat dialog with other user](https://developers.connectycube.com/android/messaging?id=create-new-dialog)
5. [Send/Receive messages](https://developers.connectycube.com/android/messaging?id=sendreceive-chat-messages)

More detailed chat code sample for Android [can be found here](https://developers.connectycube.com/android/code-samples?id=chat-code-sample)

Most of the above platforms provide a cloud hosted plan, but some of them also provide an Enterprise plan when you the whole platform can be installed at your AWS/Google/Azure account, so hence the privacy is the best because you own all your data